# Problems in playing Frame animations ,codes as follows

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

```
about two questions 
/*
```

1. this  [_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[1]]

```
 what can it do ? why ?
```

2. how  [_playerImageView startAnimating] and 
      [_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[1]] 's sequences
       Affect the results
    */

```
- (void)loadDataAndAnimation
    {
    _imageData =@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"a"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"b"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"c"]];

    [_playerImageView setAnimationImages:self.imageData];
    [_playerImageView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
    [_playerImageView startAnimating];

    }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self loadDataAndAnimation];
}

- (IBAction)playGame:(UIButton *)sender
{
NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);
if ([_playerImageView isAnimating])
{
    NSLog(@"stop");
    [_playerImageView stopAnimating];
    [_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[sender.tag]];
}else
{
    NSLog(@"start");
    [_playerImageView startAnimating];
    //  something wrong ?
    [_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[1]];

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
 [_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[1]];  // Set the Image for PlayerImageView
 [_playerImageView startAnimating];          // It will start animating
```

**First set the Image & then animate** instated of *First animate & then set the Image*

```
 this [_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[1]] //This will set image from the array objectAtIndex 1.
```

Comment: but [_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[1]] and [_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[0]] has the same effect? why ?

Comment: `[_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[1]]` for ObjectAtIndex 1 & `[_playerImageView setImage:_imageData[0]]` for ObjectAtIndex 0